# How to know which header file to include for a documented function while developing for MacOS?

Tags: c++, c, objective-c, xcode, header

I'm new to macOS development, so pardon my simplistic question. Say, if I have a function. Let's take `SCError` for example. From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemconfiguration/1516922-scerror?language=objc) I can see that I need to add:

> System Configuration framework

But how do I know which header file to add, so that I don't get `Use of undeclared identifier 'SCError`'?

PS. I'll give an example of a documentation that doesn't make me ask these questions. Say, [GetLastError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror). It states at the bottom of the page:

```
Header:     errhandlingapi.h (include Windows.h)
```

So it's clear for me what to do:

```
#include Windows.h
```

So what am I missing with the Apple documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let Xcode help. You know the framework is "System Configuration" by looking at the documentation. So in your source file start typing:

```
#import <Sy
```

and Xcode will start offering suggestions. And the first one you see after entering the above just happens to be for what you need:

```
#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
```

The basic pattern will work for most frameworks.

```
#import <FrameworkName/FrameworkName.h>
```

Again, let Xcode show you likely candidates as you start typing the first few letters. Then it's easy to select the match so the rest is entered for you.

Answer (score 2):

Several solutions:

Consult the documentation. You look at the [SCError](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemconfiguration/1516922-scerror?language=objc) documentation at it shows you it's part of the System Configuration framework (currently, in at least two places: the breadcrumbs near the top and the navigation list on the left). Usually, that's what you need to import (without spaces):

```
// Modern style.
@import SystemConfiguration;
// Old style.
#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
```

Another solution is to use Cmd+Shift+O in Xcode (File > Open quickly …). Enter `SCError`, and go to the definition of this function. Again, the breadcrumbs tell you which framework this function lives in: `Frameworks > SystemConfiguration`. This again leads to the same imports as mentioned above.

Comment: Apple used to use header names in their docs btw. I understand they encourage using modules instead, but it's clearly not as straightforward now as it was